# Как найти сумму 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + … + 1/N?

Tags: python

Дано целое число N (> 0). Найти сумму  1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + … + 1/N

```
n = input()

s = float(0)
a = float

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    a = 1 / i
    s = s + a
    i = i + 1


print s
```

что не правильно?

Comment: Здесь не решают задачи за вас, тут помогают решить задачи

Comment: Алгоритм очевиден, условно: `результат = 0; i ОТ 1 ДО N: результат += 1/i`. Покажите как решали и что не получилось.

Comment: [Формула Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4#.D0.A4.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.83.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.AD.D0.B9.D0.BB.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0)

Comment: n = input()

s = float(0)
a = float

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    a = 1 / i
    s = s + a
    i = i + 1


print s

Comment: google математический предел =)))))))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 4):

Неправильны 3 вещи:

1) `a = float` - зачем это вообще?

2) `a = 1 / i` - во 2-ом Питоне это целочисленное деление, надо `a = 1.0 / i`

3) `i = i + 1` в цикле - лишнее
Можно просто:

```
s = 0.0
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    s += 1.0 / i

print s
```

Comment: Еще можно так: sum(1.0/i for i in range(1, n))

Answer (score 2):

В одну строчку:

```
print(sum(1.0/i for i in range(1, int(input())+1)))
```